# How to prevent openlayers and geoserver to cache tiles?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I try to prevent my tiles for being cached but everything I tried wasn't a success.

I tried to :

- Uncheck tiles cache option in GeoServer
- Add a time param in the source.tileWMS :  `params: {'LAYERS': 'mylayer','TILED': true,'time': new Date().getTime()}`
- Add a random value in the source.tileWMS : `params: {'LAYERS': 'mylayer','TILED': true,'myData': Math.random()}`
- Specify cacheSize to 0 in the source.tileWMS : `cacheSize:0`
- Check 'disable cache' on Google Chrome debugger

Every time I zoom and unzoom, I get the tile in cache.

Do you have any solution?

Comment: If you do not want to cache tiles, perhaps it would be better not to even ask them and use OpenLayers in Single tile mode.

Comment: In which cache... the browser one?

Comment: @AndreaAime Well, I guess.. How can I know?

Comment: time is a valid keyword try using uniq